# Change devise flash keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using the devise gem and would like to change the flash keys from `[:notice]` and `[:alert]` to something custom. The rest of my app is using keys like `[:success]` and `[:warning]`.

Is there any way to change the key from `notice` to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Yah, I just shared the CSS between multiple names and used the Devise/rails-standard naming structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heard from those managing Devise that this isn't an option. Answer is to use the appropriate flash keys.